# Как получить дробные числа из строки из дробных чисел?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Нужно вытащить числа из let a = "(49.82501, 23.96117)";
 в две другие переменные ( в=49.82501 и с=23.96117) или в массив.

let b = a.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
но тогда я получаю 4 числа (в = 49, 82501, 23, 96117)
пробовала через parseFloat но результат NaN

помогите пожалуйста разобраться. что я не так делаю?

Comment: `a.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, может ответом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно, нужно еще проверять на наличие точки, в итоге ваше регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так:

```
/(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = '(49.82501, 23.96117)'
const arr = numbers.slice(1, -1).split(', ')
const [b, c] = arr

console.log(b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно еще вот так (не рекомендуется):

```js
let a = "(49.82501, 23.96117)";

console.log(JSON.parse(a.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска всех чисел, с десятичными дробями и без, можно использовать

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g
/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g // + отрицательные числа
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/tVnZeo/1).

Чтобы найти *только дробные числа*, удалите знак `?` из регулярных выражений.

**Подробности**

- `-?` - опциональный знак `-` (квантификатор `?` означает *0 и более повторов*)
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - опциональная незахватывающая группа:

  - `\.` - точка
  - `\d+` - 1+ цифр.

Демо на JS:

```js
let a = "(49.82501, 23.96117)";
console.log(
  a.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
);
```